# Mouseover event handler not working in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet, click, mouseover

I have a map of points (circles) on a map, draw in d3.  I have a mouseover listener event which formats the circles/adds popup when user hovers over a circle.  However, I can't get the equivalent of 'mouseover' to work on mobile (when user taps a point) and I am curious if there's a relatively straightforward solution.  Here's my current approach, which works perfectly fine on desktop:

```
// render d3 svg
var events = mapG.selectAll("circle")
    .data(allSFEvents)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", 'events')
    .style("display", initialDateMatch)
    .style("pointer-events", "all")

// Display only events on today's date
function initalDateMatch(data){
     //Do some stuff to get if today's date matches event date
     if (todaysDate === data.dateFormatted) {
        return 'inline'
        } else {
        return 'none'
        }
     }

//Finally, add popup and formatting to circle on mouseover
.on("mouseover", function(d) { 
               //add popup 
               //some code to add popup
               //set class to have special appearance
               d3.select(this).attr("class","countyHover");
          })

    .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
            //remove popup 
            //some code to remove popup
            //set class back to normal appearance
            d3.select(this).attr("class","events"); 
          })
```

Unfortunately, this does not work on mobile and clicking on the circles does nothing.  I can add:

```
.on("click", function(d) { 
               d3.select(this).attr("class","countyHover");   
          })
```

Which does work on mobile, but I am struggling to find a way to remove the popup and formatting when clicking off the point (i.e. I haven't found the equivalent of "off-click").

Comment: What do you mean by mouseover on mobile?

Comment: Rob - please see my edits above.  By mouseover, I want a listener event that will react when a user touches a point on the map, on mobile.

Comment: Can you provide a working example in a snippet and then it we can test it

Comment: Rob - I will try to figure out a snippet, but the overall code is fairly lengthy.  It works perfectly on desktop, but does nothing when clicking over the points on mobile.

Comment: adding an on - click listener event does work for mobile, but my issue is that there's no way to remove popup upon clicking off the point!

Comment: Maybe try https://github.com/mourner/Leaflet.TouchHover

Comment: I would add a transparent rect between your circles and your map (i.e. before you append the circles), giving the rect the same dimensions as your map. On that rect I would add an on click event listener that selects all .countyHover and changes their class to .events.